# Is there any way to take a number as variable's name?

Tags: json, ios13, swift4.2

I have JSON response in which there is "0" as key value for a JSON. I'm using Swift's Codable protocol to parse my JSON. Is there any way that I can take "0" as my variable's name or some other workaround for this? I know about SwiftyJSON for parsing JSON but I prefer using local swift protocol.
[This is my JSON response.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPbxv.png)

Answer (score 0):

If the "0" key is a constant, you can map it to a valid property name using `CodingKeys`, like so:

```
struct Response: Codable {
    let success: Bool
    let data: DataClass
    let error, message: String
}

struct ZeroKeyType: Codable {
    // properties go here
}

struct DataClass: Codable {
    let the0: ZeroKeyType
    let searchField: [String]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case the0 = "0"
        case searchField
    }
}
```